# Best performance stucture

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a database structure for a big project and I'm wondering what method use for the logs table.
I'm using **Laravel 5.*** with **Eloquent**.
This table will contain, **User_id, User-Agent, IP, DNS, Lang**....

**Method A :**

```
LOGS_TABLE :

| Id  | user_id  |         dns     |      ip  |     user_agent .... |
|-----|----------|-----------------|----------|---------------------|
|   1 |   5      |  dns.google.com |  8.8.8.8 |  firefox.*........  |
```

**Method B :**

```
LOGS TABLE :

| Id | dns_id | ip_id | user_agent_id |  |
|----|--------|-------|---------------|--|
|  1 |      1 |     1 |             1 |  |

IP TABLE:

| Id |  value  |
|----|---------|
|  1 | 8.8.8.8 |
```

The problem is, there is 10 fields like this and I'm afraid that all the jointures will slowed the requests.

**Why we save all the logs ? :**

Our tool provide a complete and high standing IP filtering service. The purpose is to let our customers filter their advertised traffic, and choose who is seing their website exactly.
The main purpose is to choose excactly which page they want to send Facebook on, while advertising on Facebook for example.
All the traffic of the service is due to the visitor visiting ads of our customers.
Technically we just do a 301 redirect to the good page and we log the user data on our database.

Thank's for you help.

Comment: If you are worried about performance and especially for logs I'd recommend you to take a look into a caching layer such as redis. Don't be afraid of the extra afford, I had a similiar use case and the possiblity to publish/subscribe with redis may help you too

Comment: I'm sorry I don't properly explain the problem (The logs are footprints for the services) We will read and write on this table.

Comment: I don't see an issue with that. What is your concern about?

Comment: If I use redis the data will be lost if the server reboot or crash ?
I need to keep these data.

Comment: There are different possibilities which you should definetely check out in case it's actually a "big project". As of data persistence I recommend you to read: https://redis.io/topics/persistence . Redis does snapshots of your complete data, but that's up to you as user.

Comment: I will check this thank you !

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve with the log database? If it is just inserting data, I would go for a denormalized table (option 1).
If you want to also select data on every request, both options will slow your application down. You should take a look at a nosql Database maybe.

**partitioning**
Another option can be to use partitioning, see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/partition-table

In this case you can work with a checksum of the unique data and store the corresponding data in a table with a prefix.

For example: `$checksum = 'pre03k3I03fsk34jks354jks35m..';`, store in table `logs_p` or `logs_pr`.

Do not forget to put an index on the checksum column.

Comment: I need to archive the logs because it's the goal of the service.
Our tool provide a complete and high standing IP filtering service. The purpose is to let our customers filter their advertised traffic, and choose who is seing their website exactly.
The main purpose is to choose excactly which page they want to send Facebook on, while advertising on Facebook for example.
All the traffic of the service is due to the visitor visiting ads of our customers.
Technically we just do a 301 redirect to the good page and we log the user data on our database.